# CMake: Creating a shared android library with the correct path to its shared library dependency

Tags: android-studio, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a native (no Java code) shared Android library that I can then `DllImport` from C# in the Unity game engine. Unfortunately, my code depends on a complex 3rd party shared library (`libtensorflow.so`) and I can't figure out how to link against it such that it can resolve the symbols it needs after being deployed.

When Unity creates an apk, it bundles all .so files into the same directory (see *Unity bundled directory structure*), and loading `libmy_library.so` fails because it can't find `../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflow.so`. This path is embedded in the shared library (as verified with `ndk-depends`) and I might be able to change that using some patcher, but I think there's a simple `CMakeLists.txt` modification I'm missing. Sadly, I don't know enough about how CMake, Android Studio, or shared libraries work in order to figure it out.

Every change I've tried to `set_target_properties` results in `ninja: error: 'libtensorflow.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libmy_library.so', missing and no known rule to make it`.

Omitting libtensorflow from the `target_link_libraries` results in `app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:8: error: undefined reference to [...]`.

How can I tell CMake where the `.so` I'm linking against will be while letting it find it where it is now?

---

```
$ndk-depends --print-direct libmy_library.so
liblog.so
../../../../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflow.so
libm.so
libstdc++.so
libdl.so
libc.so
```

Unity bundled directory structure:

```
├── ObjectIdentifier
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── unity-classes.jar
│   ├── local.properties
│   ├── proguard-unity.txt
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── assets
│           ├── java
│           ├── jniLibs
│           │   ├── armeabi-v7a
│           │   │   ├── libmain.so
│           │   │   ├── libmono.so
│           │   │   ├── libmy_library.so
│           │   │   ├── libtensorflow.so
│           │   │   └── libunity.so
│           │   └── x86
│           │       ├── libmain.so
│           │       ├── libmono.so
│           │       ├── libmy_library.so
│           │       ├── libtensorflow.so
│           │       └── libunity.so
│           └── res
```

---

My Android Studio Project Hierarchy:

```
├── MyLibrary.iml
├── app
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── app.iml
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   ├── proguard-rules.pro
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│           ├── cpp
│           │   ├── c_api.h
│           │   └── native-lib.cpp
│           └── jniLibs
│               ├── armeabi-v7a
│               │   └── libtensorflow.so
│               └── x86
│                   └── libtensorflow.so
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             my_library
             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED
             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/c_api.h
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib
              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

set(ANDROID_SO_OUTDIR ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/../../../MyUnityProject/Assets/MyLibrary/Plugins/Android/libs)

add_library(tensorflow-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(tensorflow-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtensorflow.so)

target_link_libraries(my_library

                       ${log-lib}
                       tensorflow-lib
                       )
#
# Copy the built library into the appropriate folder in MyUnityProject
#
add_custom_command(TARGET my_library POST_BUILD
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
   ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/libmy_library.so
   ${ANDROID_SO_OUTDIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmy_library.so)
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-v -Wall"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // let gradle pack the shared library into apk
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I found a workaround but it definitely seems to be bypassing how CMake is intended to be used:

`target_link_libraries(my_library ${log-lib} "-ltensorflow -L ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/")`